# Sync IIS Between Two Computers

Tags: iis, synchronization, metabase

I have Network Load Balancing setup to split the load between two IIS running Win2k3 boxes.  Keeping the files in sync is trivial (we use rsync), but the IIS meta data is a pain.  The current method we're using to get the metadata (the virtual directory and website info) involves using a script to export the data, copy it over, and then use another script to import the data - this seems rather convoluted - is there a better way, preferably an automated one?  We create and delete virtual directories rather regularly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://www.adsonline.co.uk/IISExport/